# Regex: Match multiple timestamps in a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file that line by line details a timestamp at the very start, and may contain other timestamps in between. The first timestamp is always enclosed in `[]`, and the ones in the middle of the line are always enclosed in `<>`. The goal is to create a regex pattern that can create groups for the timestamp and the text that follows it. I'm pretty new to regex, and I'm having a hard time with it. The text would look like this:

```
[00:22.88]Lorem <11:53.82>ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <98:23.52>adipiscing elit
[00:34.08]eiusmod <00:42.52>tempor incididunt ut <10:67.58>labore et dolore
```

However, the lines are being fed to regex one by one, so there's no need to account for other lines (although some sort of exception would be needed to match a newline at the end of the line or the end of the file...).

The desired output would be something like this (for each line):

```
[('00:22.88', 'Lorem '), ('11:53.82', 'ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur '), ('98:23.52', 'adipiscing elit')]
```

This pattern for instance, works for the very first timestamp:

```
\[(\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{2})\]\s*(.+)
```

For the rest, I wouldn't know how to do it, I tried adding `|` in between the brackets and the less than symbols in an attempt to make it match "this or that", it didn't work:

```
\[|<(\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{2})\]|>(.+)
```

I also tried this, in an attempt to match anything in between timestamps, it also didn't work.

```
\[(\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{2})\]\s*<([0-9]+:[0-9.]*)>\s*(.+)\s*
```

I would really appreciate it if somebody with more experience with regex could lend me a hand, I have no clue on how to tackle this. I did find a pretty cool website to write regex patterns which was pretty useful when trying to write my own: https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going with pure regexp splitting I'd use the following. The regexp matches `<` or `[` followed by your number pattern, then `>` or `]` for the timestamp. For the content it takes everything until the first `<` and `[` occurres.

```py
import re

regex = r"(?:<|\[)([\d]{2}:[\d]{2}\.[\d]{2})(?:\]|>)([^<\[]+)"

test_str = ("[00:22.88]Lorem <11:53.82>ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <98:23.52>adipiscing elit\n"
    "[00:34.08]eiusmod <00:42.52>tempor incididunt ut <10:67.58>labore et dolore")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

found = []

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    found.append((match.group(1).strip(), match.group(2).strip()))
    
print(found)
```

The above regexp can be visualezed and debugged with the following link: https://regex101.com/r/Pyr2J4/1

---

The above regexp might be enough for you but it fails if the text contains a `<` or `[` (e.g. "Lorem < ipsum ..."). If you like to be able to process those too, I suggest to match the timestamps only and then take the rest of the text between the matches as the content. Also the following regexp does not support timestamps like `[00:00.00>` which the above one does. This takes a little bit more python:

```py
import re

regex = r"<[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}\.[\d]{2}>|\[[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}\.[\d]{2}\]"

test_str = ("[00:22.88]Lorem <11:53.82>ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <98:23.52>adipiscing elit\n"
    "[00:34.08]eiusmod <00:42.52>tempor incididunt ut <10:67.58>labore et dolore")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

found = []
last_match_end = None

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    if len(found) > 0 and last_match_end is not None:
        # add the text from the end of the last match to the start of the 
        # current match as the text of the last match (to previous list value)
        found[-1].append(test_str[last_match_end:match.start()].strip())
        
    # take the timestamp (=match) from the current match
    found.append([match.group().strip("<>[]")])
    # save end of this match
    last_match_end = match.end()
    
if len(found) > 0 and last_match_end is not None:
    # add missing text of last match
    found[-1].append(test_str[last_match_end:].strip())

print(found)
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks a bunch for this. I'd probably go with an approach similar to the second one, since I do want to be able to have those characters. Thanks for going the extra mile and covering both cases.